# get.Range with EQUIV Function ? (Or Vlookup or Match?)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, match, vlookup

I'm new to Google Apps script, so sorry if this is a too easy question.
I've searched in the existing questions but could not make this work.

I have this function :
`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5,1).activate();` that works fine.

But instead of (5,1) I would like to have a dynamic value for the row number.
I would like to return the row number of a specific text that I chose in a list in A1.

Here is what I do :

```
function GoTo () {

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var c = "EQUIV($A$1,A2:A100,0)+1";

  { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(c,1).activate(); }

    }
```

If I put `= EQUIV($A$1,A2:A100,0)+1` in a cell, i do get the right number I'm looking for.

Thanks a lot !

Could you help me ?

Comment: Please refer https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/1Vab4UYYG_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want the following function looks in column A starting at A2 and searches for what you entered in A1. If found, it activates the cell of the found value. It also returns the row number of the found row in cell B1.

```
function findText() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var find = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()// cell of value to find in  column A
var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
      if (values[i][j] == find) {
        row = i+2;
       sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(row); //row number found to C2
       var range=sheet.getRange("A"+row)
       range.activate() //activate cell of found value
      }
    }    
  }}
```

You could run this with an onEdit trigger.